# Parsing text line by line and returning substrings with Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, file, parsing, match

I'm not really sure what I'm looking for, so please bear with me.

I have text files stored in a database and I'd like to parse them based on a value I've provided and return a string value relative to where it found a match. The best thing I can come up with is using regex to slice off everything before and after the value but that just seems stupid and overtly taxing, the file is hundreds of lines long.

Coincidentally, they're structured just like HTML so I think you could parse them as HTML if you wanted to.

```
<key>settings</key>
<dict>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#002b36</string>
    <key>caret</key>
    <string>#eee8d5</string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#839496</string>
    <key>gutter</key>
    <string>#073642</string>
    <key>invisibles</key>
    <string>#586e75</string>
    <key>lineHighlight</key>
    <string>#073642</string>
    <key>selection</key>
    <string>#2c4c55</string>
    <key>selectionBorder</key>
    <string>#586e75</string>
    <!-- Default looks best really -->
    <!-- <key>findHighlight</key> -->
    <!-- <string>#dddd45</string> -->
    <!-- <key>findHighlightForeground</key> -->
    <!-- <string>#fdf6e3</string> -->
</dict>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is searching for the instance of "background" in the `<key>` tag and returning the value in the `<string>` tag below it.

Ruby has a .match function that returns the first instance of a substring.

Comment: Easiest would be with a XML library such as Oga or Nokogiri; next easiest with built-in XML capabilities (not as nice); direct text manipulation, like regexp, last choice. What is your position on gems?

Comment: I don't have anything against gems. Why would I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Oga:

```
require 'oga'
doc = Oga.parse_xml(xml)
puts doc.at_xpath('//key[text()="background"]').next_element.text
```

Without gems:

```
require 'rexml/document'
require 'rexml/xpath'
doc = REXML::Document.new("<doc>#{xml}</doc>")
puts REXML::XPath.first(doc, '//key[text()="background"]').next_element.text
```

Regexp (not recommended, fragile):

```
puts xml[/<key>background<\/key>\s*<string>([^<]*)<\/string>/, 1]
```

Comment: undefined method `next_element' for nil:NilClass. I've accessed the file before with record.file.path but that doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Comment: I don't understand, is xml a variable that's set to the file? I'm doing doc = Oga.parse_xml(record.file.path)

Comment: Update: I manually pasted in a string of XML and it worked fine, so it's not accessing the file correctly.

Comment: Yeah, `xml` here is a string, not a file name. You will have to read the file yourself (e.g. `xml = File.read(file_path)`)

Comment: Got it to work with Oga.parse_xml(IO.read(record.file.path)). That might change in the future, though. I feel like you can do it with one less argument.